# Firefox SDK page-mod arbitrarily stops working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've created an extension using the Add-on sdk, which relies in part on page-mod.  It has been working fine.

However, at some point (I'm not sure exactly when, because I was working on a different part of the extension when it happened) the page-mod stopped working.  However, the code didn't change.

I am using the -p option to cfx when running my extension (when launching it, I type `cfx -p firefox_development_profile run` (for more see [the cfx documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/cfx-tool.html) )

When I include the profile dir, my content script doesn't work.  When I don't include it, it does.  So there is something in the profile that is causing page-mod to stop working.

I made a very basic page-mod plugin to see if there was something in my code that was causing the problem, but it has the same problem.  My test code (in `main.js` is)

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.org",
    contentScript: "alert('OPENED A MATCHING PAGE')",
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        console.log("Been attached")
    }
});
```

My `package.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "test_firefox",
  "fullName": "Test Plugin",
  "id": "jid1-0yzmDwetD2My3g",
  "description": "An addon on to work with the Dalhousie Glossary System",
  "author": "Daniel Yule",
  "license": "MIT 2.0",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

To be clear: this extension works when run with `cfx run` but does not when used with the profile dir command `cfx -p firefox_development_profile run`

Is there something in a firefox profile (which I don't remember making any changes to) that would cause page-mod to stop working?

Comment: Does this happen even with a brand new profile?

Answer (score 0):

May be this your problem :

> A page mod does not modify its pages until those pages are loaded or
>   reloaded. In other words, if your add-on is loaded while the user’s
>   browser is open, the user will have to reload any open pages that
>   match the mod for the mod to affect them.

Font : http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/introducing-page-mods-attachto

Comment: sometimes if the user closes firefox enough times without refreshing a page, when firefox is opened again, the page is not refreshed - and so the mod does not trigger